# React/Native - Absolute paths won't work when inside similar paths

Tags: reactjs, react-native, import

My project is structured like this

```
src/
+- components

+---- example1

+------- Foo.tsx

+---- example2

+------- Bar.tsx

+- flows

+---- Biz.tsx
```

the two lines that set up absolute path

```
tsconfig.json
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
 "@/*": ["./src/*"]
}
```

I've got absolute paths kinda working. If I want to import Biz into Foo/Bar, or Foo/Bar into Biz, it works. However, import Foo into Bar or Bar into Foo instead uses a relative path and doesn't recognize the absolute path. Is there a way that I can make it so it always uses relative paths?

Also, the path comes out to @/components. Is there a way that I can make it so it's @components?